# Everytime restart required for flask to work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask, flask-restful

I have a flask app which will read some dataframes and displays some output in front end. I have two `routes`. One will accept `user input` and is send to second route. Second route make use of this input and process some `dataframe` and provides some output. Issue is, if go to user input page again and if I try submitting another `input`, it gives me `page not working` error.
Is it because of any memory issue? If I restart my sever, then I repeat it once(every time I need to restart).

```
from flask import flash, redirect, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify
import math
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from . import fa
from database import connection
UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = './uploads'
if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY)

@fa.route('/fc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('fc.html',flag=0)

@fa.route('/fc/s', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def start():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            material_number = request.form['ma']
            path = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY
            extension = 'xlsx'
            os.chdir(path)
            result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
            allFiles = result
            frame = pd.DataFrame()
            list_ = []
            for file_ in allFiles:
                df = pd.read_excel(file_)
                list_.append(df)
            frame = pd.concat(list_)
            frame = frame.reset_index(drop=True)
            df1 = frame[frame['Ma'].str.contains(ma,regex=True)]
            pr = df1['Pr'].unique().tolist() 
            pro = pd.read_excel(r'~pathhiddn~\dtrvsproj.xlsx')
            return render_template('fc.html',flag=1,ma=ma,prs=pr)
    return redirect(url_for('fa.index'))
```

Comment: Debug your code, check in which line, it stops working, like put the print statement before/after you do something with dataframe, and also before return, and be sure where it's stuck.

Comment: Can we see what the error is in your logs?

Comment: what i understood is the for loop part is having issue..until that it works well

Comment: when I removed all code from : `path = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY` to `pro = pd.read_excel(r'~pathhiddn~\dtrvsproj.xlsx')` it is working fine

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel(file_)
list_.append(df)` these lines are causing issue.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.chdir(path)
```

This was causing the issue. I removed that and replaced `df = pd.read_excel(file_)` with `df = pd.read_excel('./uploads/data/'+file_)`